# SQL Server 2008. Allow Remote Connections?

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2000 and 2008 installed on a Windows XP Pro box. I can connect to both db instances locally.

From another box, a Windows 7 box, I can connect to the SQL 2000 instance on the first box but I cannot connect to the 2008 instance using the same SQL Server authentication credentials that worked locally.

Allow Remote Connections is set to TRUE for both the 2000 and 2008 database instances.

What else can I look for to be able to connect to the remote 2008 instance from the Windows 7 box?

I am trying to connect using Mgt Studio 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try connecting by specifying a port,

eg:
servername,1433

or

servername\instance,1433

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess, is the 2008 SQL instance configured to be "listening" for TCP connections? (It wasn't on a box I recently checked.)  To Determine, drill down to:

- Start, Microsoft SQL Server 2008, Configuration Tools, SQL Server Configuration Manager
- SQL Server Network Configuration
- Protocols for [instance name]
- There should be four items listed: Shared Memory, Named Pipes, TCP/IP, VIA

For your environment, which should be enabled and which should be disabled? Most setups call for Shared Memory and TCP/IP enabled, the others disabled.

Comment: Weird. I swore this worked before, but when I try to bring up the Config Mgr I get the error: "Cannot connect to WMI provider."

Comment: Marc's Rule: "If the problem doesn't make any sense, you probably have more than one problem."

Answer (score 3):

I solved by enabling the SQL Server Browser service (setting to automatic and start it).

Answer (score 1):

I faced this Error and I solved that with doing this:

1. Launch the SQL Server Configuration Manager from the **"Microsoft SQL
   Server 2005 CTP"** Program menu
2. Click on the **"Protocols for SQLEXPRESS"** node,
3. Right click on **"TCP/IP"** in the list of Protocols and choose, **"Enable"**

That's it, After that I could open my DB in visual studio 2010 without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a firewall possibly stopping the port that 2008 is listening on?

Comment: Shouldn't the port for 2000 be the same as 2008, port 1441?

Comment: I am not sure of that. It is for multiple instances of the same version, but I am not sure that 2000 and 2008 can listen on the same port. I have not tried installing both on one machine.