# Can't see *all* databases in a remote SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server

I can connect to a remote SQL 2008 Server instance, but I cannot see all the databases in the instance using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

I suspect that my problem has something to do with not all database in the remote instance having the same version. For example, I "upgraded" a 2005 database to 2008 by doing a backup from 2005 and importing it into 2008.

When I realized that this was not one of the database that I could see from my other PC, I noticed that the compatibility level of the imported was still 2005, so I changed it to 2008. Still I could not see the database.

On that remote server, the instance node is named "sql2008", and is "Version 10".

When I connect to the sql2008 remote instance from my local PC, the connection is shown locally as being a "SQL Server Version 8.0" instance.

I suspect that locally, I am only being shown databases that are somehow in the remote 2008 instance but have not been upgraded.

I guess I don't know what constitutes an upgraded database and I don't know how to connect to see all the databases, even if this requires multiple connections from the source PC.

The local machine is Windows 7 Ultimate. The remote host is Windows XP Pro.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885989/sql-server-2008-allow-remote-connections) -not being able to see the SQL Server 2008 instance.

## Update:

This is what I see on the remote server using Mgt Studio, namely, a SQL 2008 instance and a 2000 instance.

[image]

When I log onto the SQL 2008 instance and perform the following query

SELECT
   @@VERSION As Version,
   SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') as ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS,
   SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') As ServerName,
   SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') As MachineName

The result re-confirms that the 2008b instance shown above with a version of 10 is a 2008 instance:

```
    Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (Intel X86)   Mar 29 2009 10:27:29   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition on Windows NT 5.1 <X86> (Build 2600: Service Pack 3) 

USPL-DOKMANC2   USPL-DOKMANC2\SQL2008B  USPL-DOKMANC2
```

OK, now from my LOCAL box, I used SQL Mgt Studio to try and connect to USPL-DOKMANC2 (the remote box.)

[alt text http://content.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/ec146f56-5651-4968-9286-82508dc5d3b2/2010-05-22_1426.png](http://content.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/ec146f56-5651-4968-9286-82508dc5d3b2/2010-05-22_1426.png)

...I connect to the remote w/o the port I get this error:

[alt text http://content.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/d3c5bc46-c286-4708-a2f5-282fc76124cb/2010-05-22_1427.png](http://content.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/d3c5bc46-c286-4708-a2f5-282fc76124cb/2010-05-22_1427.png)

But if I enter the DEFAULT port, I am able to connect. Note that the SQL2008 connection that I just added appears as being version "8" (SQL 2000).
[alt text http://content.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/ea80af5e-4a1f-4417-9327-0b76476b4d14/2010-05-22_1426.png](http://content.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/ea80af5e-4a1f-4417-9327-0b76476b4d14/2010-05-22_1426.png)

I seem to be connecting to my SQL2000 instance again even though I specified in my connection params to connect to SQL2008b, a 2008 instance.

I can't seem to see my remote 2008 instance on uspl-dokmanc2. I keep getting my 2000 default instance databases showing up under sql2008b.

**2nd Update:**

Based on excellenf feedback below that SQL is most likely disregarding the name of the instance when tryingt o connect and determining the instance from the port specified. Now I just need to know the port that the SQL2008b instance is running on. I expected that SQL Mgt Config would tell me. The port is blank. Does this imply a default port? What would it be for 2008, not ethat I already have another 2008 instance, so if they all have to have separate ports, the normal 2008 default is probably not it.

Here's what I see in SQL Mgt Config for the 2008b instance. No port mentioned:

[image]

Comment: Does the SQL or Windows login you are using have permissions to all of the databases?

Comment: Yes, it should. I am logging on with the sa (admin) account.

Comment: I believe that you are getting close to the problem by suggetsing that SQL Server is using the specified port to identify the instance rather than what I specify in my connection parameters. I would like to run SQL Serfver Config Mgr and check the port of the 2008 instance but I am getting the rror "Cannot connect to WMI Provider. you don't have permision (doubt it) or the host is unreachable (probably). Is there anotehr way to tell the port , perhaps, via a query? Or maybe you know how to reolve teh error so I can run th config mgr?

Comment: OK. I fixed my SQL Config Mgr issue (see link below, if interested) and now I am trying to figure out where it tells me the port 2008b instance is running on. Getting close...
(http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinpoon/archive/2009/11/27/sql-server-configuration-manager-cannot-connect-to-wmi-provider-invalid-class-0x80041010.aspx)

Comment: Did you try using the IP of the host machine instead of the machine name? This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

The remote instance (8.0) is a SQL Server 2000 instance

There is no such concept as "database version" that relates to visibility or permissions: every DB on a given server (version, SP and hotfix included) is at some internal version. This is why you can't restore or attach a SQL Server 2008 DB onto SQL Server 2005

I would run this to get the full details

```
SELECT
   @@VERSION,
   SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS'),
   SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName'),
   SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')
```

For example, you may have a client alias that means you're connecting to the wrong server.

Also, you have to explicitly [`DENY ANY VIEW DATABASE TO public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189077.aspx) to "hide" databases

Comment: Re: "The remote instance (8.0) is a SQL Server 2000 instance". No I don't believe it is. I am sure that I am not connecting to the wrong server. I am not trying to attach a 2008 db onto SQL Server 2005, rather, a 2005 db was restored into a 2008 instance. I'll momentarily post an update to my question that will hopefully, clarify. ty.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your 2008 instance uses 1433 port? MS SQL seem to disregard a name of a instance and connect with the given port in most cases. Use the Configuration Manager to check the port.

Also, check if the SQL Browser is available from the remote machine - you'll have to add 1434 on UDP to your firewall settings. Remember to make sure that the SQL Browser is running on your server of course. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277

Comment: I think your on to something. I just need to know the port of the 2008b instance, since that seems to be key in identifying which instance to connect to. I am in SQL Config Mgr for 2008. Where is it? http://content.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/377bd6b7-2932-48f5-b85f-f2d3d91b09d8/2010-05-22_1607.png

Comment: You're in the right dialog - just scroll down. You might also want to change from a dynamic to a static port (just copy whatever value you have in TCP Dynamic Ports to TCP Port).