# What port is my SQL2008 instance running on?

Tags: sql-server

Check out this pic  of my SQL 2008 Management Configuration screen for TCP: [image]

I need to know what port I am running on. Based on [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888985/cant-see-all-databases-in-a-remote-sql-server-instance), I don't believe that it is 1433, which I guess is the default.

When I check my port number in SQL Config Mgr., it is blank. Does this suggest a default port? Note that I have multiple SQL Server instances on the db server. One 2000 instance and two 2008 instances. I want to know the port of the 2008b instance.

The first display is for TCP. I'm not sure what VIA is, but check it out:

[image]

Can you help?

**Update**

I restarted my sql2008b instance and checked the log to look for a msg that indicated the port that it was using. It showed this:

```
2010-05-22 20:06:29.27 Server      A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2010-05-22 20:06:29.27 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQL2008B ].
2010-05-22 20:06:29.27 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\MSSQL$SQL2008B\sql\query ].
2010-05-22 20:06:29.32 Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 5786].
2010-05-22 20:06:29.32 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening locally on port 5786.
```

Yet, when I tried to log on using the following as the server name:

(local)\sql2008b,5786

I still was unable to connect, while logged onto the remote box (hence using "local".)

A suggstion was made below to set the port myself. This occurred to me to try but there are a couple of things that are botehring me:
1) Why can I connect to  my SQL 2000 instance without monkeying with anything to get it to work (but not my 2008 instance)?
2) The IP addresses shown in TCP1 and 2 don't appear correct. The one I blacnked out, presumably theIP address of my router and the one needed to make my server visible on the Internet, was not correct. Also , the local 192.168.1.100 was not correct. The db server server's IP adress end in a different number. perhaps I sh

Comment: @George - From your log it still doesn't as though it is set up right. It only shows an entry for the DAC which is a dedicated Administrators Connection. You should make sure that remote connections are enabled in the Surface Area Configuration tool. You should also make sure that the SQL Browser service is running so you don't have to go to the bother of typing port numbers when making a connection and can just use the name of the instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCP/IP is disabled in your screenshot so it isn't listening on any port. On start up when enabled it will write an entry to the SQL Server logs telling you what port it is listening to. (Accessible through Management Studio tree view Management -> Sql Server Logs nodes)

You might find this link useful [How to configure an instance of SQL Server to listen on a specific TCP port or dynamic port](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938)

Also do you have the [SQL Server Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx) service running on that machine (it might help you connecting to the right instance)?

Comment: If it were disabled, could the db even work locally? I would assume not. It does. I just can't connect to it remotely. When I enable TCP, the port is still blank. Can multple instance all listen on teh default port 1433, presumably? Emabling the port didn't help me so I can connect to it.

Comment: @George Yes. It uses shared memory for  (local) connections. No only one instance can listen per port.

Comment: Thanks very much. Then, if the port is shared, I am at a lost with my previous question which remains and issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888985/cant-see-all-databases-in-a-remote-sql-server-instance

Comment: @George: "Shared memory" is an IPC method, like Named Pipes.  It's not a "shared port."  It doesn't work over TCP and you can't connect to a remote server that way.

Comment: @George: You can enable TCP and hard code a specific port number (say 1435) into the TCP Port field.

Answer (score 1):

If TCP/IP is disabled, the service can still listen via Named Pipes (for network connections) or Shared Memory (for local connections), so it will work with TCP/IP disabled if you choose to got that route.

On startup, there will be an event log entry to tell you what connection methods it's listening for, or you can do a "NETSTAT -A" from the command line to see which ports the server is listening on in general.