# Connect To Proper Remote SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

On our development server we have three versions of SQL Server installed (SQLEXPRESS 08, SQL2008 R2, and SQL 2012).

In the services, I can see the following instances:

```
SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
SQL Server (SQL2008)
```

When I open all three servers in SQL Mgmt Studio and connect to all three servers, I see the following names for the servers:

```
(local) (SQL Server 11.0.3128 - OBX1\Administrator)
(local)\SQLEXPRESS (SQL Server 10.50.2500 - OBX1\Administrator)
(local)\SQL2008 (SQL Server 10.50.2500 - OBX1\Administrator)
```

When I connect to the server at the IP address or server URL, it connects to the the `SQLEXPRESS` instance but I need to connect the 2012 instance, which is the at `(local) (SQL Server 11.0.3128 - OBX1\Administrator)`.

No matter what I try, I can't get connected to any instance besides the default one, which for some reason seems to be SQLEXPRESS.

Looking for an example of the proper connection value for the other instances??

Screenshot below:
[image]

If I RDP to the server and open up SQL Mgmt Studio I have three options for servers to connect to, `(local), (local)\SQL2008, (local)\SQLEXPRESS`. If I select `(local)` and run the command to get servername and version I get `OBX1` for the name and `2012` for the version. If I select `(local)\SQL2008` and run the same commands I get `OBX1\SQL2008` and `SQL Server 2008 R2(sp1)` and if I select `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` and run the command I get `OBX1\SQLEXPRESS` and `SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1)`.

Given this addition info, how do I connect the instance that is just `(local)` remotely with the IP Address? Is this possible?

Again, currently if I connect remotely at `the_ip_address` it connects to the SQLEXPRESS instance. And if I try to connect to, for example the SQLEXPRESS instance like so, `the_ip_address\SQLEXPRESS` it connects to the SQLEXPRESS instance again.

Comment: might be better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What have you tried using to connect? The three instances have different names, so there should be no issue in connecting to a particular one of them.

Comment: I have tried the following as the Server name:
`the_actual_ip_address\(local)`,
`the_actual_ip_address\(MSSQLSerVER)`,
`the_actual_ip_address\MSSQLSERVER` and similar for the other instance but I always get the message that says it can't connect to that instance

Comment: I think in order to connect to named instance you will need to have "SQL Server Browser Service" running. Plus I would check if TCP/IP protocol is enabled for other instances.

Comment: Your descriptions of which instance is which is confusing. Can you post a screenshot of SQL Configuration Manager ([like this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GN0cv.png)) that shows the instance names and state, and indicate which one you're trying to connect to? Also I agree with @JackLock about the browser service and making sure that TCP/IP is enabled (also accessible via configuration manager). Finally there is no such thing as `ip address\(local)` or `ip address\(MSSQLSERVER)`.

Comment: @JackLock I have double checked both TCP/IP protocol and it is enable. I have also double checked that the SQL Server Browser server is running. first is enable and the other is running.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have added the screen shot.

Comment: So to connect to the one named MSSQLSERVER you just use `the_ip_address`. Check `SELECT @@SERVERNAME; SELECT @@VERSION;` once connected.

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.stackoverflow.com. Duplicate of this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/104922/sql-server-connection-string-question.

Comment: @NicholasCarey I disagree that it belongs on serverfault. I'd say it's better suited at dba.stackoverflow.com, even if the duplicate is at serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to identify and subsequently specify the portnumber as well. Ie:

```
tcp:MyServer,7701
tcp:MyServer,7704
```

Note that the portnumbers above are from one of my installations - yours may very well be different.

To identify the portnumbers, go to the SQL Server Configuration Manager and look under SQL Server Network Configuration. You should see separate entries for your instances here, and the properties for each instance should include a TCP Port or Dynamic Port or similar.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889751/806549) answer may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Duplciate of this: https://serverfault.com/questions/104922/sql-server-connection-string-question

To connect to a named SQL Server instance, you can:

- Specify the server (machine) name and instance name in the connect string:

  ```
  Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
  ```
- specify the specific port and either the server (machine) name or IP address:

  ```
  Server=myServerName,1437;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
  Server=123.98.76.45,1437;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
  ```

  **Note:** Specifying port 1433 will [usually] get you the default, unnamed SQL Server instance on the machine (but not always as it depends on how SQL Server has been installed and configured). Note also that specifying an explicit port *and* and instance name makes no sense whatsoever.

And when in doubt, visit http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for pretty much any database out there [though connecting/configuring Oracle connections is its own peculiar form of hell].

Comment: Very good point that explicit port and instance makes absolutely no sense. Obvious, really, but I never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the **SQL Browser service**, but it is most likely running.  Also ensure TCP protocol is enabled for each service using **[SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672.aspx)** application found in the SQL Server program group.  You will find these settings under **SQL Server Network Configuration**.  [Some versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190198%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of SQL have TCP/IP disabled by default.

I'm not sure if the 2012 SQL Server configuration will see the other instances, so you may have to make the change in multiple places.  I'd start in the 2012 Config Manager.

Specifying a port number when an instance is set up to use dynamic ports is probably not a good idea.

Some applications require you to set a static port - typical with JDBC apps.

If you're still having issues, check into firewalls.  Portqry and telnet can help test connectivity.